# Convert byte array to string has special characters C#

Tags: c#

I am going to convert byte array into string using below method.

`string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Data);`

But this string has the following special characters which I needed to avoid from the string itself.

[image]

As you can see in the data I am getting space before the '7h' and some '\rL' getting added after the text. I used trim() function. But it didn't work for the following case.

Please advice.

Comment: whats the actual string?

Comment: Use the correct encoding, not the `Default` one. Don't ask us which is the 'correct' one as only you can know.

Comment: Is it possible the source of your data is wrong?

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is based on the system's active code page, and probably doesn't match the encoding of `e.Data` at all. You probably want `Encoding.UTF8` or `Encoding.Unicode` or similar

Comment: Actual string is 'https://qrs.ly/1o9h530'. I used QR code online tool to generate the QR code for the above text. Once I scan the QR code, I am getting the above text instead of the text which I used

Comment: `Encoding.Default` should have been called `Encoding.Random`; you almost never want to use it

Comment: are you sure the " 7" & the carriage return + other symbol are not actually in e.Data - it could be the online tool to generate the QR code is at issue, not the conversion.

Comment: Where does `e.Data` come from? More code please!

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here. How was the QR code generated? How was it's value read into your app? Are you doing anything to the value before decoding?

Comment: @PaulF, most probably that might be the reason.will check

Comment: Some barcode scanners allow prefix & suffix data to be added to the scanned code - so that could be another source of unexpected characters - quite often people want carriage return appending to move to the next field in their application.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly symbols you whant remove, just replace it:

```
var data = "⏩Some⏬String";
            var clearedData = data.Replace("⏩", string.Empty).Replace("⏬", string.Empty);
```

result:

> SomeString